# Can I mark two "any" as same thing in a TypeScript function signature?

Tags: typescript

Consider the following function:

```
function extractItemsFromArray(array: any[], isItemToBeRemoved: (item: any) => boolean) {
  let removedItems = [];
  let i = array.length;
  while(i--)
    if(isItemToBeRemoved(array[i]))
      removedItems.push(array.splice(i, 1));
  return removedItems;
}
```

Its signature says: I accept array of `any` items and a checker function that decides whether to remove an item of type `any`.

However, if a function with signature `(item: string) => boolean` is passed as `isItemToBeRemoved` and an `number[]` is passed as `array` (I assume that both are asserted to some types) than the above function definition won't tell TS that it's actually not ok. Is there a way to mark those 2 `any` in the definition of `extractItemsFromArray` as same type things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, while writing the question I googled a bit, and decided to read more about [Advanced Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html). It seems that type aliases is actually what I'm looking for:

```
function extractItemsFromArray<T>(array: T[], isItemToBeRemoved: (item: T) => boolean) {
  ...
}
```

and the usage seems to be:

```
let roots = extractItemsFromArray<INode>(dictionaryCopy, item => !item.parentId);
```

Comment: Not type aliasses. Generic type parameters, but yes that is the way to do it

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir ah, thanks for correction, [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) is the required docs ref, not the one mentioned in the answer